# How to input an empty parameter in pandas .value() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, trading, algorithmic-trading

streamlined my question. I am looking to create a method that filters input price types. Below is a sample of the data:

```
Open    High    Low     Close
1189.73 1214.01 1188.63 1198.72
1198.67 1201.41 1193.77 1196.35
1195.69 1203.60 1170.78 1176.45
1176.47 1185.01 1172.68 1176.65

adj_price_list = df.values[1:5, [1,2,3,4]].tolist()

['1189.73', '1214.01', '1188.63', '1198.72']
['1198.67', '1201.41', '1193.77', '1196.35']
['1195.69', '1203.6', '1170.78', '1176.45']
['1176.47', '1185.01', '1172.68', '1176.65']
```

Objective:

- A smarter method to filter O/H/l/C input selection. Currently using multiple if-else statements.
- Problem: I can't use 'None' as a parameter

  ```
  adj_price_list = df.values[1:5, [1,4]].tolist()
  ['1189.73', '1198.72'] #Open and Close prices

  adj_price_list = df.values[1:5, [2,3]].tolist()
  ['1214.01', '1188.63'] #High and Low prices
  ```

---

To rnso:

```
def GetList(px_open=True, px_high=True, px_low=True, px_close=True):
    lst = [px_open, px_high, px_low, px_close]
    return [(i+1) if lst[i] else None for i in range(4)]

get_list = GetList(False,True,False,True) #Output: [None, 2, None, 4]

get_price_list = df.values[1:5, get_list].tolist()

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, thanks for the advise. Edited my question to make it more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Good! Upvoted. Need a bit more info. What is your expected output for this data?

Comment: Why have you changed the question completely? where are all those `if-else` statements for which you wanted some alternative? You can add an edit but not delete significantly from the original question.

Comment: `df.values[1:5, [0,1,2,3]]` works and not `df.values[1:5, [1,2,3,4]]` . Counting starts from 0 here and there is no column number 4 in df.

Answer (score 0):

Following can be used in place of `if-else` part:

```
def getlist(px_open=True, px_high=True, px_low=True, px_close=True):
    lst = [px_open, px_high, px_low, px_close]
    return [(i+1) if lst[i] else None for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Hi rnso, thanks for the advise. Tried your method but still encountered the error - I pasted my output above. Great to have your comment

Comment: Above code was to replace your `if-else` statements. Put them back in the question and I can show how to modify your code. Currently it is not clear what you want to do with `[None, 2, None, 4]` output. Do you want to get row numbers 2 and 4?